# I want to display the sale price of variable product on the product page when the regular price and sale price of product are same.How can I do this?

Tags: php, woocommerce

This question is related to woocommerce. I have changed the get_price_html() in `class_wc_product_variation.php` such that there is no comparison between regular and sale price and sale price become independent of regular price. But when I enter the values of regular and sale price as same,the price is not displayed in the product page. the code of function is as follows, Further I changed another function in the same folder in the file named `class-wc-product-grouped.php`.

```
public function get_price_html() {

        $price =  woocommerce_price( $this->sale_price ) ;

        if($this->sale_price!=$this->regular_price && $this->sale_price==$this->regular_price)

        $price = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', $price, $this );

        return $price;

}
```

in the else part of the function I changed

```
function is_on_sale{
    return !empty( $this->sale_price ) && $this->sale_price == $this->price || $this->sale_price == $this->regular_price ? true : false;
}
```

this function resides in `class-wc-product-grouped.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation, it seems your if condition will always return false.

It requires that 1. sale price and regular price are not equal AND 2. Sale price and regular price are equal. That's a contradiction

Comment: I removed the if condition totally then too the sale price is not displayed when I keep regular and sale price as same.